# Prevent "Invitation:" prefix to calendar invites in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using my personal GMail calendar to send an invite to my work account. I use Outlook 2016 at work for my calendar. For some reason Outlook decides to prefix all such invites with "`Invitation:`" which is useless and annoying to me.

For example, this (abbreviated) ICS from GMail:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20170721T133000Z
DTEND:20170721T153000Z
DTSTAMP:20170717T062956Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Jeroen Heijmans:mailto:redactedredactedredacted@gmail.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Meeting with John
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Will show like this in Outlook:

> Invitation: Meeting with John @ Fri Jul 21, 2017 15:30 - 17:30 (CEST) (redacted@example.com)

Which contains:

- "Invitation: " prefix
- "@" with complete time frame (which is duplicated info)
- the addressee e-mail at the end

I just want the "SUMMARY" to be the Subject, e.g.:

> Meeting with John

How do I stop Outlook from adding all that cruft for invites?

Answer (score 0):

via the Outlook web UI, add the calendar using the "invite.ics" button. (ref screenshot) For safe measures, you may want to accept the invitation afterwards, though I'm not sure if this step makes any difference. Do the above every time a new invitation or update comes in.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihV17.png)

Comment: Thx for the response. But using Outlook Web would be a _workaround_ for me, I'd prefer to just use Outlook itself...